# How to write a key-value pair object Schema in mongoose

Tags: json, database, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have tried hard to create a schema like this but didn't get a solution yet.

I tried to do something like this.

```
 questions: {
    type: new Schema({
      questionId: {
        type: String,
      },
      correct: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
    }),
  },
```

the output i need is:

```
questions: {
  [questionId1]:[boolean],
  [questionId2]:[boolean]
}
```

Example:

```
questions:{
 23:true,
 29:false
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think i need to use type:Map but not getting idea for how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schema can be done with Map as saksh73 already pointed out (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps)

```
const Example = new Schema({
    // your stuff
    questions: {
        type:Map,
        of: Boolean
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work well with already existing object where initially I had some pre-defined key-value structure and later decided to make it completely dynamic. The users of that data won't expect the map to be returned but instead a plain js object

Comment: You can always use "{}" to indicate mixed content. That basically disables the structure check for a certain part of the schema. In my opinion the map is still better since it fits perfectly to the use case of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean key-value pair using this:

```
const abc = new Schema({
      questionId: {
        type: Map,
        of:Boolean
      },
});
```

and if you want to have an object instead of a boolean...You can do it like this:

```
const abc = new Schema({
      questionId: {
        type: Map,
        of:new Schema({
          id: Number,
          title: String,
        }),
      },
});
```